# Issue when sending Parameters update by postman put method Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on `.net core 6.0` web api . i face issue on

testing `web api` by post man .

my issue how to send paramters to web api update

method .

so How to send id with object on body to update action .

```
{
    "itemId": 4,
    "itemNameAR": "قلم",
    "itemNameEN": "pen2",
    "costTypeId": 1,
    "minLimitQunatity": 1,
    "costAccountID": 1,
    "departmentID": 1,
    "itemCategoryId": 1,
    "description": "1",
    "hasExpireDate": true,
    "isActive": true,
    "createdBy": 1,
    "modifiedBy": 1,
    "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "modifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "itemattribute": null
}
```

when send api as below

```
https://localhost:7235/api/items?id=4
```

so How to solve issue please ?

```
   [HttpPut("{id}")]
          public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, UpdateItemCommand command)
          {
              if (id != command.Id)
              {
                  return BadRequest();
              }
              return Ok(await Mediator.Send(command));
          }
```

what i try to send `api request` Web Api Not catched or hitted although i run my web api .

[image: Api not hit]

**Updated post**
i change url on post man as below

```
https://localhost:7235/api/4
```

but still issue not solved

error display 400 bad request
details error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Fax": [
            "The Fax field is required."
        ],
        "City": [
            "The City field is required."
        ],
        "Phone": [
            "The Phone field is required."
        ],
        "Region": [
            "The Region field is required."
        ],
        "Address": [
            "The Address field is required."
        ],
        "Country": [
            "The Country field is required."
        ],
        "PostalCode": [
            "The PostalCode field is required."
        ],
        "ContactName": [
            "The ContactName field is required."
        ],
        "ContactTitle": [
            "The ContactTitle field is required."
        ],
        "CustomerName": [
            "The CustomerName field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-efde167cb6a7fa5af42abff9d055e2db-92ff55a318cb7a29-00"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request URL to,

```
https://localhost:7235/api/items/4
```

because your controller has been configured as,

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
```

which indicates a path parameter rather than query parameter.

Comment: i add as answer but  issue not solved

Comment: what's the error now?

Comment: i add error on original post above

Comment: You now get 400 which means the URL path is working. The request you sent does not match the expected data model UpdateItemCommand.

Comment: yes thanks solved only need to know error 400 refere to what

Comment: can you please tell me what this message 400 refere to what ?

Comment: The first question is what the UpdateItemCommand model looks like? can you show the code?
In your Postman, your request body is an object, {"itemId": 4, ...} but the error message says missing Fax, City... so I am guessing your post body does not match the required UpdateItemCommand model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249876/discussion-between-charles-han-and-ahmed-barbary).